# How to make JQuery UI work with specific parts of JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So you call on Jquery to make the three --- lines and it stacks the menu.  Well is there a way to not call all of jquery.min.js.  It breaks some older code of jquery UI.  Which part of the code only helps break down the menu and may possibly not break the JQuery UI?

I have tried Jquery version 2.1.0 and 1.12.2 and 1.10.0, but they all break the Jquery ui.

I also tried the Jquery compatibility mode, but it makes it so that the menu doesn't work in Bootstrap.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_1_12_2 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

I even found something that looked like a work around, but didn't seem to help:

https://github.com/frappe/jquery-ui-bootstrap

Here are the Scripts that are ran:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/style/js/jquery.form-2.47.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../bootstrap/jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/style/js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/style/js/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js"></script>
<script src="/style/js/jquery-ui-1.8.1.dialog.min.js"></script>
```

My menu is basically this one, but the rest of the site works with JQuery UI:
http://www.bootply.com/soljohnston777/KZXTGaVsgE#

[image]

Comment: http://projects.jga.me/jquery-builder/  in here I found dimensions and CSS to load just for JQuery.  It is as minimal as I can get it, but still it gets in the way of JQuery Ui.

Comment: Trying to get Bootstrap and jQuery UI styles/JS to work together is not going to end well. You're going to run into so many conflicts that you're basically better off coding an entire solution based off one framework, that emulates the other (but doesn't actually use any of its code), like the git repo you linked to.